# removing the blue borders in a summary element using css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, focus

I'm making my firs steps learning to code. I've been taken some courses on Internet and now I decided to continue learning from the experience while I build a Wordpress child theme.

The thing is that I made a summary. And when it's active it has a blue border.

[image]

I'm trying to remove it but I can't find a solution.

I tried suing this without success:

```
summary:active {
    border:none;
}
```

Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: can you write codes here?

Comment: It could be that the item has `focus`. Having the blue line around it helps people using a keyboard know where they are, and from an accessibility perspective it's best to leave it there or restyle it.

Comment: use outline: none in your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove it from all `input`s

```
input {
  outline: none;
}
```

To remove it from all tags use the universal selector [`*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors):

```
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
summary:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

The browser is rendering a border around the summary while it is on focus.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:** `Its not the border` but a outline that browsers render.

**Solution:** `Set outline:none` on the element.

So the code would be

```
summary:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the input field, not the summary class itself. You can try removing it by using the following code:

```
    input:focus{
        outline:none;
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If it is an input field try this

```
input:focus{
  outline: none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

People have said to remove with `outline: none`, which will remove the outline.

However, from an accessibility perspective you should **replace the outline** with one that fits the brand guidelines.

The `outline` on an element's `focus` state is to ensure that someone can tell where they are. Not all users have a point-and-click device, and even if they do, they won't leave their mouse hovering over an element at all times. For field inputs it's worth keeping an `outline` or other `focus` style so users know which field they're in.

The [A11y Project (accessibility project) has some useful information which covers what I've said](http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/).

I'd suggest that rather than doing:

```
summary:focus {
  outline: none !important
}
```

You talk to the designer to come up a positive `focus` style, e.g.:

```
summary:focus {
  background: #ffeeee;
  color: #242424;
  outline: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the blue outline disappear in Safari 10 with:

```
summary {outline:none;}
```

Funny thing is that I can't change the specific color of the outline:

```
summary:focus{outline:red;}
```

Αlso removed the outline. Using `solid` and `dotted` all work as specified, and display it black.

But it looks like the blue color is hard-coded into focused input fields. The very text box I'm using right now has the same light blue outline. Maybe that can't be changed, but you can suppress its visibility or restyle it. You just can't specify a color.

Answer (score 0):

```
*.no-outline > * :focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

This would remove any the outline for any tag with class `no-outline`, and also it will remove outline for all its children.